# When rendering an array of components, when a button is clicked always the latest element of the array is picked up

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-hooks

could someone please provide an in-depth explanation why something like this would not work in React? What happens is, that every time the button is clicked the value "name" from the last element in the array is picked up. So, in the following example the dialog will always display the name "John2".

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Dialog, DialogContent } from "@material-ui/core";

function Employee({ name, dialogOpen, setDialogOpen }) {
  const aDialog = () => {
    return (
      <Dialog open={dialogOpen}>
        <DialogContent>{name}</DialogContent>
      </Dialog>
    );
  };
  const handleClick = () => {
    setDialogOpen(true);
    aDialog();
  };

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {aDialog()}
      <button onClick={handleClick}>{name}</button>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

function App() {
  const employeeNames = ["John", "John1", "John2"];
  const [dialogOpen, setDialogOpen] = React.useState(false);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {employeeNames.map(name => (
        <Employee
          name={name}
          dialogOpen={dialogOpen}
          setDialogOpen={setDialogOpen}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here all I think all three dialogs as `true` value passes for all three dialogs. Try using some id for each name or name itself as id. i.e

```
  const [dialogOpen, setDialogOpen] = React.useState(null);
```

And try calling

```
setDialogOpen(name);
```

and pass true false with given logic

```
   <Employee
      name={name}
      dialogOpen={name===dialogOpen}
      setDialogOpen={setDialogOpen}
    />
```

Comment: I have verified this by using React developer tools. What was happening is what @prasid444 suggested, that the dialogOpen boolean property was set true for all the Employee components. So, all the dialogs where appearing on top of each other.